# How to display a moving array in the output console?

Tags: c

What's the better way than what I have done below:

system("cls") does the job but clearing the screen will later on mess with whatever that I want to display, the other negative side effect is the annoying blinks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int a[5]={1,0,1,1,0};
int b[5]={0,0,1,1,1};


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    while(1){
        //display the arrays
        for(int i=0; i<=4; i++){
            printf("%d ",a[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        for(int i=0; i<=4; i++){
            printf("%d ",b[i]);
        }
        //shift every cell by 1
        for (int i = 4 ; i >= 0; i--) {
            a[i] = a[i - 1];
            b[i] = b[i - 1];
        }
        sleep(1);
        system("cls");
        //keep generating 0s and 1s for the 1st cell of arrays
        a[0] = rand() %2;
        b[0] = rand() %2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not quite understand what you want us to do? Please ask a specific question about a specific problem. In what way the code that you posted does not work?

Comment: @user14063792468 I did mention my code works but rather asking is there a better way to do it ? I have to clear the entire screen to display the updated array.

Comment: When my terminal gets `cls` command, it outputs that command not found.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is the `\r` character, it will go to the beginning of the line without creating a new one. It will enable you to overwrite previously written characters

Comment: @ShellCode - except he is outputting on two lines.

Comment: @user14063792468 : because you are not running on Windows perhaps?  It is a valid command in cmd.exe.  That is just another reason why using `system()` is a poor solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without platform/terminal specific code that is not possible as there is no platform independent way to place the cursor or clear the screen.

The best you can do that is largely platform independent is return to the start of the *current* line, or back-space on the current line.  That is to say you can only move the cursor backward on the current cursor line:

What you can do is:

1. Replace `printf("\n");` with `printf("\t");`
2. Replace `system("cls") ;` with:

```
        printf("\r");
        fflush(stdout) ;
```

The output will be on one line with a TAB separation, and the line will be overwritten on each iteration.

```
1 1 1 0 1       1 0 1 0 0
```

Failing that you can either:

- Use a platform independent console library such as ncurses,
- On windows use the native [Windows Console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions).
- Where supported use [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

The last option is simplest and while for a long time was not supported in Windows, Windows 10 now supports ANSI ESC sequences, so there are few reasons not to use that for this simple screen handling.

For example `ESC[0;0H` moves the cursor to the top-left. In this case you would simply replace the "cls" with:

```
        printf( "\x1b[0;0H" ) ;
```

Note that in this case you also need either a newline or `fflush(stdout)` before the `sleep()` to ensure the second line is output before the clear screen:

```
        printf("\n");            // Force output flush
        sleep(1);
        printf( "\x1b[0;0H" ) ;  // Home cursor
```

If you have other content on the screen before this and you don't want to redraw everything, you could move the cursor by:

```
        printf("\n");            // Force output flush
        sleep(1);
        printf( "\x1b[2A" ) ;    // Cursor Up two lines
```